# libSVM for unbalanced data

Tags: svm, libsvm

I'm using libSVM for binary classification and my training data is very unbalanced (-1:90%, +1:10%). According to libSVM's documentation, it's better to set different penalties for positive and negative classes. For example, the SVM problem is:

$\min\limits_{w,b,\xi}  \frac{1}{2}{\bf w^Tw} + C^+\sum\limits_{y_i=1} \xi_i + C^-\sum\limits_{y_i=-1} \xi_i$

My question is which penalty should be larger and why. Thanks

Comment: Check out [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F221112311_Applying_Support_Vector_Machines_to_Imbalanced_Datasets%2Ffile%2F5046351b0229e207bd.pdf&ei=47SPU-HnG5aWqAanhYCADQ&usg=AFQjCNHyZ23NvEq87WMeizGN0I88mmVeZw&sig2=XisZd_z8rURfzJi01tCrcg&bvm=bv.68235269,d.b2k). It shines some light on ideas on how to deal with unbalanced data.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @nickb. Would you mind adding a brief summary of the information in that paper in case the link goes dead, &/or so readers can know if they want to pursue it further?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The larger the penalty, the more an error on the training set (which is what is measured by $\xi_i$) for a pattern of that class influences the model.  So if you have more negative patterns than positive patterns then you probably want to make $C^+$ larger than $C^-$.  Personally if there is a class imbalance problem then it usually means that the costs of false-positive and false-negative errors are not the same, and the relative costs of the errors is an important criterion for adjusting the penalties.  I would suggest using cross-validation to estimate the expected loss and choose the penalties to minimise that.

Comment: A small addition: In practice, I have found that often in unbalanced problems, different penalties yield the same CV performance. So, OP, keep in mind that changing penalties will not necessarily improve your results in CV.

Comment: @Bitwise, what would you do in this case then?

Comment: @user11689 there is not much to do, this is just another parameter to play with to try and improve your results (with proper CV, of course).